# Find intersection point ray/triangle in a right-hand coordinate system

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I would like to get the intersection point of a line (defined by a vector and origin) on a triangle.
My engine use right handed coordinate system, so X pointing forward, Y pointing left and Z pointing up.

---

---- Edit ----

With Antares's help, I convert my points to engine space with:

```
p0.x = -pt0.y;
p0.y = pt0.z;
p0.z = pt0.x;
```

But I don't know how to do the same with the direction vector.

---

I use the function from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178874/how-to-get-the-intersection-point-ray-triangle-intersection-c), original poster use [this tutorial](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution?url=3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution).

First we look for the distance t from origin to intersection point, in order to find its coordinates.
But I've got a negative t, and code return true when ray is outside the triangle. I set it outside visualy.
It return sometime false when I'm in the triangle.

Here is the fonction I use to get the intersection point, I already checked that it works, with 'classic' values, as in the original post.

```
float kEpsilon = 0.000001;

V3f crossProduct(V3f point1, V3f point2){

  V3f vector; 

  vector.x = point1.y * point2.z - point2.y * point1.z; 
  vector.y = point2.x * point1.z - point1.x * point2.z; 
  vector.z = point1.x * point2.y - point1.y * point2.x; 

  return vector;
}

float dotProduct(V3f dot1, V3f dot2){

  float dot = dot1.x * dot2.x + dot1.y * dot2.y + dot1.z * dot2.z; 

  return dot;
}

//orig: ray origin, dir: ray direction, Triangle vertices: p0, p1, p2.  
bool rayTriangleIntersect(V3f orig, V3f dir, V3f p0, V3f p1, V3f p2){ 

// compute plane's normal

  V3f p0p1, p0p2;

  p0p1.x = p1.x - p0.x; 
  p0p1.y = p1.y - p0.y; 
  p0p1.z = p1.z - p0.z; 

  p0p2.x = p2.x - p0.x;
  p0p2.y = p2.y - p0.y; 
  p0p2.z = p2.z - p0.z;

  // no need to normalize
  V3f N = crossProduct(p0p1, p0p2); // N 

  // Step 1: finding P

  // check if ray and plane are parallel ?
  float NdotRayDirection = dotProduct(N, dir); // if the result is 0, the function will return the value false (no intersection).

  if (fabs(NdotRayDirection) < kEpsilon){ // almost 0 

      return false; // they are parallel so they don't intersect ! 
  }

  // compute d parameter using equation 2
  float d = dotProduct(N, p0); 

  // compute t (equation P=O+tR P intersection point ray origin O and its direction R)

  float t = -((dotProduct(N, orig) - d) / NdotRayDirection);

  // check if the triangle is in behind the ray
  //if (t < 0){ return false; } // the triangle is behind 

  // compute the intersection point using equation
  V3f P; 

  P.x = orig.x + t * dir.x; 
  P.y = orig.y + t * dir.y; 
  P.z = orig.z + t * dir.z; 


  // Step 2: inside-outside test
  V3f C; // vector perpendicular to triangle's plane 

  // edge 0
  V3f edge0; 

  edge0.x = p1.x - p0.x;
  edge0.y = p1.y - p0.y;
  edge0.z = p1.z - p0.z;

  V3f vp0; 

  vp0.x = P.x - p0.x;
  vp0.y = P.y - p0.y; 
  vp0.z = P.z - p0.z; 

  C = crossProduct(edge0, vp0); 

  if (dotProduct(N, C) < 0) { return false; }// P is on the right side 

  // edge 1
  V3f edge1;

  edge1.x = p2.x - p1.x;
  edge1.y = p2.y - p1.y;
  edge1.z = p2.z - p1.z;

  V3f vp1; 

  vp1.x = P.x - p1.x; 
  vp1.y = P.y - p1.y; 
  vp1.z = P.z - p1.z; 

  C = crossProduct(edge1, vp1); 

  if (dotProduct(N, C) < 0) { return false; } // P is on the right side 

  // edge 2
  V3f edge2;

  edge2.x = p0.x - p2.x;    
  edge2.y = p0.y - p2.y;
  edge2.z = p0.z - p2.z;

  V3f vp2; 

  vp2.x = P.x - p2.x;
  vp2.y = P.y - p2.y;
  vp2.z = P.z - p2.z;

  C = crossProduct(edge2, vp2);

  if (dotProduct(N, C) < 0) { return false; } // P is on the right side; 

  return true; // this ray hits the triangle 
}
```

My problem is I get t: -52.603783

intersection point P : [-1143.477295, -1053.412842, 49.525799]
This give me, relative to a 640X480 texture, the uv point: [-658, 41].

Probably because my engine use Z pointing up?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51459/3301) help?

Comment: At first glance, no: My coordinate orientation problem would be the same, while using many more multiplications. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can change the sign of ONE component of each point/vector prior to do your calc with that algorithm, to account for its left handedness. Then return the boolean as expected.

Comment: Reblochon Masque > thank you. That's what i did, following Antares advice, but i don't know how to do the same for the direction vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My engine use right handed coordinate system, so X pointing forward, Y pointing left and Z pointing up.

You have a slightly incorrect idea of a right handed coordinate system... please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions.

As the name suggests, X is pointing right (right hand's thumb to the right), Y is pointing up (straight index finger) and Z (straight middle finger) is pointing "forward" (actually -Z is forward, and Z is backward in the camera coordinate system).
Actually... your coordinate components are right hand sided, but the interpretation as X is forward etc. is unusual.

If you suspect the problem could be with the coordinate system of your engine (OGRE maybe? plain OpenGL? Or something selfmade?), then you need to transform your point and direction coordinates into the coordinate system of your algorithm. The algorithm you presented works in camera coordinate system, if I am not mistaken. Of course you need to transform the resulting intersection point back to the interpretation you use in the engine. 
To turn the direction of a vector component around (e.g. the Z coordinate) you can use multiplication with -1 to achieve the effect.

Edit:
One more thing: I realized that the algorithm uses directional vectors as well, not just points. The rearranging of components does only work for points, not directions, if I recall correctly. Maybe you have to do a matrix multiplication with the CameraView transformation matrix (or its inverse M^-1 or was it the transpose M^T, I am not sure). I can't help you there, I hope you can figure it out or just do trial&error.

> My problem is I get t: -52.603783
>
> intersection point P : [-1143.477295, -1053.412842, 49.525799] This give me, relative to a 640X480 texture, the uv point: [-658, 41]

I reckon you think your values are incorrect. Which values do you expect to get for t and UV coordinates? Which ones would be "correct" for your input?

Hope this gets you started. GL, HF with your project! :)

Comment: In this case you could search for an intersection algorithm tailored for IdTech3. Also, I don't think you need to do a matrix multiplication but just a rearranging of the point components and maybe changing the sign (multiplication by -1 on a single component, not the whole point/vector). Like this: IdTech3Point.x = -yourPoint.y, IdTech3Point.y = yourPoint.z, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@GUNNM: Concerning your feedback that you do not know how to handle the direction vector, here are some ideas that might be useful to you.

As I said, there should be a matrix multiplication way. Look for key words like "transforming directional vector with a matrix" or "transforming normals (normal vectors) with a matrix". This should yield something like: "use the transpose of the used transformation matrix" or "the inverse of the matrix" or something like that.

A workaround could be: You can "convert" a directional vector to a point, by thinking of a direction as "two points" forming a vector: A starting point and another point which lies in the direction you want to point.

The starting point of your ray, you already have available. Now you need to make sure that your directional vector is interpreted as "second point" not as "directional vector".

If your engine handles a ray like in the first case you would have:
Here is my starting point (0,0,0) and here is my directional vector (5,6,-7) (I made those numbers up and take the origin as starting point to have a simple example). So this is just the usual "start + gaze direction" case.

In the second case you would have:
Here is my start at (0,0,0) and my second point is a point on my directional vector (5,6,-7), e.g. any t*direction. Which for t=1 should give exactly the point where your directional vector is pointing to if it is considered a vector (and the start point being the origin (0,0,0)).

Now you need to check how your algorithm is handling that direction. If it does somewhere ray=startpoint+direction, then it interprets it as point + vector, resulting in a movement shift of the starting point while keeping the orientation and direction of the vector.
If it does ray=startpoint-direction then it interprets it as two points from which a directional vector is formed by subtracting.

To make a directional vector from two points you usually just need to subtract them. This gives a "pure direction" though, without defined orientation (which can be +t or -t). So if you need this direction to be fixed, you may take the absolute of your "vector sliding value" t in later computations for example (may be not the best/fastest way of doing it).